# STM32 F3 I2C on Port F SCL Push-Pull Failure

Tags: stm32, i2c

We're currently using STM32F373CC micros in several of our designs.  Part of our standard design has an EEPROM connected via I2C.  We have our own hardware layer that is tried and proven over the decades.  However, it relies on the I2C port pins having pull-ups connected externally.

On some of our new designs we have designed out the pull-up on the SCL line and have set the port pin to Push-Pull mode.  In theory, this should be no problem.  However, what we've found is that the micro seems to be treating the port pin as open-drain regardless of the setting.  For this particular design, we're using PF6 and PF7 as SCL and SDA respectively. With no pull-up connected, the SCL line is flat-lined.  With internal pull-up enabled, the SCL line is pulsing, but the rise time is so long it's not working.

Nothing in the reference manual or the datasheet says anything about this issue.  In the errata sheet we have (V4), there's quite a bit about the GPIO and I2C, but nothing that seems to relate to this.

For what it's worth, I'll copy and paste the relevant bit of the initialisation:

```
   switch( kasPinMap[eSCL].lwI2CNum )
   {
   case 1: RCC_APB1ENR.I2C1EN = TRUE; nI2CEEpsRegisters = (void*)&I2C1_CR1; break;
   case 2: RCC_APB1ENR.I2C2EN = TRUE; nI2CEEpsRegisters = (void*)&I2C2_CR1; break;
   }

   //configure the pins
   DIO_vConfigure( kasPinMap[eSCL].ePort,  kasPinMap[eSCL].lwBit,  DIOkeM_Alternate, DIOkeD_PushPull,  DIOkePU_None, DIOkeSP_Medium, kasPinMap[eSCL].lwAFN );
   DIO_vConfigure( kasPinMap[eSDA].ePort,  kasPinMap[eSDA].lwBit,  DIOkeM_Alternate, DIOkeD_OpenDrain, DIOkePU_None, DIOkeSP_Medium, kasPinMap[eSDA].lwAFN );

   //reset and enable the peripheral
   nI2CEE_vReset();
```

In the debugger, GPIOF looks like this:

[image: GPIO IMage]

AFR values are set to 4.

The I2C registers look like this:

[image: I2C registers]

And the RCC registers look like this:

[image]

Our Technical Director mentioned that to comply with the I2C standard and allow for multi-master mode, both SCL and SDA should both be open-drain. However, all we have here is the F3 and the EEPROM.

Any thoughts on why we might not be getting the push-pull action out of the SCL line would be appreciated.

Comment: I received this from ST: 

such behavior is reasonable, as STM32 internal pull-up has about 30k~50k resistance.

anyway, when the I2C IP is enabled, I2C SCL+SDA pins are set to be open drain, for some STM32 chips, and STM32F373 might be the case.

The issue is that, you can't change your hardware, to add external pull-up. you may workaround by slowing down I2C clock frequency, for example, 20kHz clock may work, if not - try 10kHz. slow clock like 10kHz should ​not be an issue for EEPROM.